# Multiple File Uploads using Struts 1.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload, struts, struts-1

I am looking for concrete examples that used plugins for uploading multiple files (selecting multiple files in a single window by using ctrl+click). Right now I am having the upload page as a dialouge box and using form.ajaxsubmit which I am using like:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          modal: true,
          draggable: false,
          resizable: false
        });
$('#upload-document-dialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 600,
      modal: true,
      draggable: false,
      resizable: false,
      buttons: {
        "cancel": function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          $("#FileUploadDocumentForm")[0].reset();
          $('#UploadDocumentAlertTR').hide();
          $('#ajaxUploaderForDocument').hide();
        },
        "upload": function() {
          var fileName = $("#fileInput").val();
          if (fileName == null || $('#fileInput').val().length == 0) {
          $('#UploadDocumentAlertTD').text('Please specify a document to upload');                
            return false;
          }

          //setting some values here for the action class
          disableDialogButtons();
          $('#FileUploadDocumentForm').ajaxSubmit(FileUploadDocumentFormOptions);
          return false;
        }           
      }
    }).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
  });

</script>
<div id="upload-document-dialog" title="Upload Document">
<form id="FileUploadForm" name="FileUploadForm" method="post"  scope="request"
        action="<html:rewrite module='/common' action='/FileUpload'/>"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          Document:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="fileInput_1" type="file" name="file[]" size="60"
                                      title="Browse for a Document to Upload."/>
        </td>


    </tr>
 </form>
</div>
```

As above I am using Ajax submit to submit the form and Form File in the action class to do the server side validations and return the results. This is working fine for single file upload . But how do I get this working for multiple file uploads. I am not having much luck to get this thing working for multiple uploads. Please suggest me how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: I was trying this usinh HTML5 but when in the multipart form ...i am only getting latest file. Any suggestions on this??